# Зачем нужна функция delete[]?

Tags: матрицы, массивы, память, функции

Зачем нужен этот код? В комментарии написано "// Освобождение ДП, занятой массивом указателей на строки  матрицы" Программа по работе с матрицей - чтение из файла, запись в файл.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
            delete[] pMatrix[i];

delete[] pMatrix;
```

Comment: это не совсем функция.

Нужно, что бы удалять массив, созданный вызовом `new[]`.

А вся эта конструкция удаляет выделенную память под двумерный массив. Почему именно так - просто он так создавался.

Comment: [Почитайте тут][1]

[1]:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/